# Slide Menu from action bar

Tags: android

I want to know how can implement a slide menu from action bar, something like this app.
A slide menu from top of app with a play buttom.

[RMF FM](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gruparmf.rmffm)

If there are library or a orientation how can I do it

[image]

Comment: Nothing helpful to add, but this app looks poorly designed IMO. You should look elsewhere for inspiration.

Comment: thanks, but my friend has an internet radio and ask me develop something like that

Comment: shame. I think you will have to make drawables for the actionbar and panel and implement the interface yourself. make a actionbar class that extends GestureDetector and contains a view for the panel. when the user swipes down on the area change the position of the panel. ...not sure if I am helping or stating the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Action Bar but implement a view that looks like one and has this sliding part.

Comment: ty, I looking for slide menu library from top